# How can I generate a TX CAN frame with a correct form using STM32 HAL_CAN libraries?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus, hal

I have started developing CAN applications using an STM32 microcontroller and HAL libraries. So I have some questions to do in order to testing an application that will transmit two characters in an infinite loop.

I'm working with a Discovery kit with the STM32L4F6 microcontroller. I've configured the CAN controller parameters via the HAL_CAN library. There, I have noticed that using this library, the user can only have access from the ID frame field to the end of the data field (for transmissions). I must guess that the CRC, ACK and EOF fields are configured in the HAL lowest layers, independently of the user code. Am I wrong?

- If not, hence, what does it mean if the ESR register contains an 010 error field that indicates "form error" (according the datasheet) when I debug my code?
- If I'm wrong, please, where can I fill in these fields or how do I access them through the HAL_CAN driver (of course, from my user code)?

Here is my configure frame parameters:

```
CAN_HandleTypeDef HCAN_Struct; // Type defined in HAL third-party library

void Can_ConfigureFrame(void)
{
    //TX
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->StdId = 0x321;
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->ExtId = 0x01; // 29 bits
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->IDE   = CAN_ID_STD;
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->RTR   = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->DLC   = DATABTXLONG;//1-9
    HCAN_Struct.Instance->MCR &= (~(uint32_t)CAN_MCR_DBF); // Descongelar el bus CAN en modo debug bit --> dbf=0
}
```

Here is the init function where more parameters are configured and those ones:

```
void App_Task_CAN_init(void)
{
    static CanTxMsgTypeDef        TxMessage;
    static CanRxMsgTypeDef        RxMessage;

    /* Configuracion timing para obtener 500kb/s */
    HCAN_Struct.Instance = CAN1;

    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg = &TxMessage;
    HCAN_Struct.pRxMsg = &RxMessage;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_6TQ; // Segment point at 87.5%
    HCAN_Struct.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.NART = DISABLE;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.RFLM = DISABLE; // FIFO locked mode disabled
    HCAN_Struct.Init.TXFP = DISABLE; // Prioridad de tx por id (más bajo más     prioridad)

    if (HAL_CAN_Init(&HCAN_Struct) != HAL_OK)
    {
        TaskCan_Error_Handler();
    }
    Can_ConfigureFrame();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know CRC and EOF  fields are not software configurable. They are done by the CAN controller hardware.

Comment: @KooroshHajiani I think so, but since I have got "form error" code at ESR register I want to ensure I was not missing anything. Lot of thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CRC, ACK and EOF are indeed not configurable by software since they are specified in the [CAN standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/63648.html) and implemented by hardware.

Under  **42.7.6 Error management** in the  [STM32F43xxx Reference Manual p.1368](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/b0/ac/3e/8f/6d/21/47/af/DM00151940/files/DM00151940.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00151940.pdf):

> The error management as described in the CAN 
>   protocol is handled entirely by hardware 
>   using a Transmit Error Counter. (TEC value, in CAN_ESR register) and a Receive Error Counter (REC value, in the CAN_ESR register), which get incremented or decremented according to the error condition. For detailed information about TEC and REC management, refer to the CAN standard.

I can't judge why the Form Error occurs. Maybe you should double-check your GPIO configuration.

Comment: Or to be more precise, CRC entirely depends on the rest of the message and can thus not be changed. And the other two are a "fixed"/"constant" part of the protocol and thus can not be changed either.